# In Webpack, how do I access font resources in my SCSS using file-loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, webpack-4

I have all my fonts in `/webfonts/`. Some of my fonts are in a subfolder within `webfonts` like `/webfonts/Lato`.

However, I'm getting a 404 for the fonts within the subfolder.

This is the error I'm getting in the console:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I'm importing my fonts in my scss file like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('../webfonts/lato/Lato-Light.ttf');
    font-weight: $light;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

How can I access these font resources within my scss?

This is my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'app.min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    plugins: [
                        'transform-class-properties',
                        'transform-object-rest-spread'
                    ],
                    presets: ['env', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: ["source-map-loader"],
                enforce: "pre"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]'
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
              test: /\.svg$/,
              loader: 'svg-url-loader',
              options: {
                limit: 10 * 1024,
                noquotes: true,
              }
            }
          ]
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        hot: true
    }
};
```

Comment: have you required de scss file in your app?

Comment: @zebnat yes, I have an `import './scss/styles.scss';` in my app.js file. All other styles are applying but I'm getting a 404 only on fonts that are within the subdirectory

Comment: fileloader looks legit. make sure the path from de scss to the font is right. And make sure the path is case sensitive. Or just copy the ttf into the same folder as the scss file and try with ./fontname.ttf